# Subtract Daily amount from Withdraw Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `tblWithdraw` and `tblProfit`.

tblWithdraw Table

```
WithdrawId    Date           User        Price
-----------------------------------------------------
1          2021-02-09       SANDANUWAN  2000.00
2          2021-02-09       GAYAN        300.00
3          2021-02-09       KASUN       1500.00
4          2021-02-09       AMAL        4000.00
5          2021-02-09       UDARA        340.00
6          2021-02-09       SULIN        200.00
7          2021-02-09       PERERA       120.00
```

tblProfit Table

```
Id  Date        Inv.No     ItemName       ItemCode  Qty CostPrice   DiscountPrice       Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2021-02-09  INV0000001  DELL LAP      LP001     5   1500.00     1900.00            9500.00        
2   2021-02-09  INV0000001  HP MOUSE      MO001     7   2500.00     2940.00           20580.00  
3   2021-02-09  INV0000001  PACIFIC FAN   FAN001    6   2000.00     4000.00           24000.00  
4   2021-02-09  INV0000001  SAMSUNG PHONE PH001     8   1000.00     1350.00           10800.00
```

This is my question. I want to sum all price from `tblWithdraw` table according to the date. Its mean withdraw date and profit table must be match. New I want to sum all amount from `tblProfit` table.Then I want to Subtract like this `Price - Amount`. Finally I want to show total amount of Profit table after subtracted. I used following join but is not working well. please help me to solve this problem. I want to subtract according to the date.

```sql
Select MAX(w.Date)Date, SUM(w.Price)Price, SUM(p.Amount)Amount
From tblWithdraw w
Left Join tblProfit p
ON w.Date = p.CurrentDate
Group by w.Date
```

Out put is like this. its wrong.

```
Date        Price       Amount
2021-02-09  33840.00    454160.00
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2012 or 2017? Express or not? What does this have to do with C#? Don't tag spam, add only what's related to your question.

Comment: *"I used following join but is not working well"* What isn't working about it? What's "wrong" with the results you get? What are the results you expect?

Comment: @Larnu I am using sql server 2017 . I used C# as my programming language . Can you please help me

Comment: So you want the solution in C#, not SQL? If so, show us your C# not your SQL.

Comment: Withdrow Price sould be 8460 and Profit Amount should 64880 after sum

Comment: @Larnu I need Sql solution.

Comment: You're joining on date only, which means that you're going to get a cartesian product (sum of each table multiplied by each other). I'd suggest a set of CTE's or temp tables to grab aggregates and then join those to each other

Comment: @Eli I no have any idea how to do that. Can you please send me code

Comment: There is no ciolumn `CurrentDate` in your table `Profit`, where is that value coming from?

Comment: @Larnu tblProft table has Date Column

Comment: *"I need Sql solution."* Then don't tag [tag:c#]; as I said, don't tag spam, just tag what it related to the question. There's nothing C# related in this question, so you shouldn't be tagging it.

Comment: Yes, but `Date` <> `CurrentDate` @sandanuwandharmarathna . We don't have access to your instance, or your knowledge, so we don't know if `date` is actually meant o be `currentdate`, or it's a different column entirely. In your attempt, you use `currentdate`, which implies a different column to `date`.

Comment: @sandanuwandharmarathna I posted my CTE idea as an answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my CTE-based approach based on the comment which I made on the initial question.

```
WITH WithDraw AS(
   SELECT 
         [date]
        ,SUM(price) PRICE
   FROM tblWithdraw 
   GROUP BY [date]
),
Profit AS(
    SELECT 
         [date]
        ,SUM(amount)AMOUNT
    FROM tblProfit
    GROUP BY [date]
) 
SELECT 
     W.DATE
    ,W.PRICE
    ,P.AMOUNT
FROM WithDraw W
INNER JOIN Profit P ON w.date = p.date;
```

Comment: Woow. Thank you @Eli. Its working as expected. I have one question. I want to subtract AMOUNT - PRICE then I want to show result in another column. Can you please send me code for that. You can edit above code

Comment: pleasure - enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, this is how I'm reading it:

```
Select w.Date, 
       w.agg_price_by_date, 
       w.agg_price_by_date - COALESCE(p.agg_amount_by_date, 0) AS diff_price_amount
From (SELECT Date,
             SUM(Price) AS agg_price_by_date
        FROM tblWithdraw w
       GROUP
          BY Date
     ) w
Left Join
    (SELECT CurrentDate,
            SUM(Amount) AS agg_amount_by_date
       FROM tblProfit
      GROUP
         BY CurrentDate
     ) p
ON w.Date = p.CurrentDate
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. Your answer is correct. But diff_price_amount must be 64880 not -56420.00

Comment: 64880 is just the sum of all the amounts. I thought you wanted to "Subtract like this Price - Amount" What is being subtracted then?

Comment: Error 2546. Ops. No dear I want to sum both column and next I want to subtract Amount - Price . I already do it. You can see answers. Thank you for your help.